# When referencing attached documents at the end of a sentence in parenthesis do you capitalize the first letter?

Tags: capitalization, parentheses

The aging reports are used by management to determine what files should be worked on first (see aging reports attached).

Comment: In the instant case, the sentence does not terminate in a period before the opening parentheses, therefore the parenthetical is a part of the sentence and does **not** being with a capital letter. The same meaning can be conveyed by terminating it and then opening the parentheses with a capital letter. In other cases, it depends on what is intended to convey.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Is the term *aging reports* in the parentheses the title of the documents attached or merely a description of those documents? If it is a title, capitalize. If not, don't.